# Pascal error: ; expected but . found

Tags: pascal, lazarus

Pascal:

> ; expected but . found

When I change my code around to fix it, it then doesn't display the answer. Can't see what I've done wrong. (It's part of a bigger program hence the block at the end and the procedure). If you know how to fix this or an easier way to write it out I'd appreciate it. It needs to remain with a function though.

```
procedure temperature;
  function Sum(var F,M:integer):integer;
  var
    c:integer;
  begin
    M:=(F-32);
    c:=M*(5 div 9);
    writeln('In Centigrade that is ',c);
    writeln('Give me the temperature in Fahrenheit to convert to Centigrade');
    readln(F);
    writeln(sum);
    readln;
  end;
  procedure finished;
  begin
  end;
begin

  initialise;
  repeat
    displaymenu(choice);
    case choice of
      1: throwdice;
      2: heightweight;
      3: textwords;
      4: temperature;  
      0: finished;
    end; 
  until choice=0;
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: Learn to properly format your code, and you'll be able to see where begin and end line up, and can easily spot the missing ones.

Comment: I took your advice and formatted it properly, but there aren't any missing begins or ends. I've looked thoroughly.

Comment: Your code is a mess. You've got two local functions (functions within the function), and are missing the `end;` at the end of your function. You're also missing the `begin` that starts your program's execution, and the `program` declaration at the top, and the entire body of your program (which is between `begin` and `end.` following all of your function implementations, and which calls those functions).

Comment: @Dorthvlader: no, you didn't format your code properly.  Your `procedure temperature` seems to end with `end.` and that can't be right. It looks as if your function Sum is a nested procedure in temprature. If so, then you did not have a body for temperature. So format your code properly, and you'll see what is missing. Outer procedures should never have an indent, so procedure finished is either not an outer (aka global) procedure, or it is not properly formatted and some parts of temperature are missing.

Comment: @Dorthvlader Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If it's pascal code then your programs have to start with:

```
program MyProgram;
```

and end with:

```
end.
```

The general form of a procedure definition is as follows:

```
procedure name(argument(s): type1, argument(s): type 2, ... );
  < local declarations >
begin
  < procedure body >
end;
```

So, each procedure must to have at the end keyword: `end;` 
At the end of procedure `temperature` is : `end.` and compiler says that it expect `;` but `.` found because `end.` must be only at the end of program but not procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional repeat loop does not have a begin, nor an end. If a while, if, repeat-until, try-else etc has more than one line of code in it, you must use a begin and an end. (end; not end.).

So, formatted properly, your code should be:

```
 procedure temperature;
  function Sum(var F,M:integer):integer;
  var
    c:integer;
  begin
    readln(F);{This line needs to be first to get F to use in the calculation. This program is all wrong. Read from what? You must define the file you are reading from - ReadLn(FileName,VariableToReadTo)} 
    M:=(F-32);{Make sure you are declaring these somewhere.}
    C:=M*(5 div 9);
    writeln('In Centigrade that is '+IntToStr(C));{Need to define file to WriteTo. You also must Append the file to write to it.}
    writeln('Give me the temperature in Fahrenheit to convert to Centigrade.');{Need to define file to WriteTo. You also must Append the file to write to it.}

    writeln(sum);{Need to define file to WriteTo - WriteLn(FileName, VariableToWrite). You also must Append the file to write to it.}
    readln;{This line does not have any arguments. What is this supposed to do? Is your program finished?}
  end;
  procedure finished;{Empty procedure}
  begin
  end;
begin
  initialise;
  repeat
    begin{Didn't have this. Need begin and end because of multiple lines.}
        displaymenu(choice);
        case choice of
        1: throwdice;
        2: heightweight;
        3: textwords;
        4: temperature;  
        0: finished;
    end; 
  until choice=0;
  readln;{What does this do??}
end.a{Characters outside of code end.}
```